# How much time does it take for pending payments to be converted into the Stripe balance?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How much time does it take for pending Stripe payments to be converted into the Stripe balance?

*I am trying to transfer some money from Stripe to Bank account and I am getting **"Insufficient funds in Stripe account"**. Can I solve this somehow or I have to wait until balance appear on my account?*

[image]

Comment: The delay before funds become available for transfers varies by country -- it's 7 days in most countries and 2 days in the US and Australia. You should write to Stripe's support directly if you have more questions about this: https://support.stripe.com/email.

Comment: Uf, that is some time. Wrote to Stripe as well. Thanks so much for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Balance was not pending anymore after 6 days. Stripe support says that it takes about a week just the first time. After that it takes about 2 days.

Comment: Is this apply for Test Mode too ?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Allow charging 'Balance' to test account urgently that developer can test stripe integration

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('Your_Test_SK');
$stripe->charges->create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => 'tok_bypassPending',
  'description' => 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs)',
]);
```

use `tok_bypassPending` as value of `source` charge test account balance urgently
**API Documentation:** https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create
**Test Token Documentation:** https://stripe.com/docs/testing?lang=php#cards-responses
Move to 'Tokens' Tab, first will be this token
[Token Documentation Screensot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55otJ.png)